# Mocha node HTTP testing - socket hang up

Tags: node.js, sockets, promise, mocha.js

I am trying to learn testing with node, for that I am using the Mocha framework.

I am trying to make a get request to a express server, performing a calculation of two numbers and returning it as a `{result: sum}` structured object.

However, i get a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with the reason: socket hang up. I've done some research and my conclusion thus far is that the error is thrown on the server when the client stop listening for the response of the request send, before the server sends it's response. 
(if wrong, I wouldn't mind some clarification).

This is my Mocha test:

```
const expect = require("chai").expect
const PORT = require("../server").PORT
const app = require("../server").app
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const BASE_URL = `https://localhost:${PORT}/api/calc/`
let httpServer;
describe("testing endpoints for calculator Rest API", function () {

    before("starting the server..", function(done) {
        httpServer = app.listen(PORT)
        console.log("server is started")
        done()
    })

     describe("testing the add endpoint", function(){
         console.log("testing the API now!")
         it("add endpoints result should evaluate to 10", function(){
            fetch(`${BASE_URL}add/5/5`)
            .then(response => expect(response.result).to.be(10))
         })
     })
     after("shutting down the server..", function(){
        httpServer.close()  
     })

})
```

and this is my stacktrace:

```
jonas@jonas:~/Desktop/testdemo1$ mocha
testing the API now!


  testing endpoints for calculator Rest API
starting server..
server started
    testing the add endpoint
      ✓ add endpoints result should evaluate to 10
(node:1949) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://localhost:1234/api/calc/add/5/5 failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/jonas/Desktop/testdemo1/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1444:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:1949) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1949) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.


  1 passing (55ms)
```

The test passes, however I get this long nasty warning, what does it mean and how would I get rid of it?

---

EDIT

```
describe("testing endpoints for calculator Rest API", function () {

    before("starting the server..", function(done) {
        httpServer = app.listen(PORT, done)
        console.log(`server listening on port:${PORT}...`)
    })

     describe("testing the add endpoint", function(done){
         it("add endpoints result should evaluate to 10", function(){
            fetch(`${BASE_URL}add/5/5`).then(response => expect(response.result).to.be(10)).then(done).catch(done)
         })
     })
```

gives stacktrace:

```
  ✓ add endpoints result should evaluate to 10
(node:27175) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://localhost:1234/api/calc/add/5/5 failed, reason: socket hang up
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/jonas/Desktop/testdemo1/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1444:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
(node:27175) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27175) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: I am having an exactly same issue...

Comment: @Rouz should you find a solution, then please post as answer :)

Comment: Funny thing is that for me this is not deterministic. It fails at at random calls. It somethimes does not fail at all. I am trying to create an integration test, so this really kills me...

Comment: holy smokes, I did manage to fix my issue but it most certainly is not the same problem that you are having. I don't even think it is worth to be an answer since the issue is super specific to my codebase (server was restarting in the middle of  the integration test). Sorry mate

Comment: @Rouz haha, that is alright. Congrats on the fix though. I will keep on the fixing :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `done()` in your tests, in the callback when the test is finished. The `done` function is passed to the callback you use in the `it` block. Also, you should make sure to always catch your errors https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code

```
const expect = require("chai").expect
const PORT = require("../server").PORT
const app = require("../server").app
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const BASE_URL = `https://localhost:${PORT}/api/calc/`
let httpServer;
describe("testing endpoints for calculator Rest API", function () {

    before("starting the server..", function(done) {
        httpServer = app.listen(PORT)
        console.log("server is started")
        done()
    })

     describe("testing the add endpoint", function(){
         console.log("testing the API now!")
         it("add endpoints result should evaluate to 10", function(done){
            fetch(`${BASE_URL}add/5/5`)
            .then(response => {
              expect(response.result).to.be(10)
              done();
            }).catch(e => done(e)) // or just .catch(done)
         })
     })
     after("shutting down the server..", function(){
        httpServer.close()  
     })

})
```

Comment: ending with done() in the it functions does sadly - not solve the warning :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `done` after the asynchronous operation has completed, currently you're calling `done` before the http server has a chance to start and you're never calling done when closing the http server. You can simply pass `done` to the all of the asynchronous callback handlers.

```
before("starting the server..", function (done) {
    httpServer = app.listen(PORT, done) // <- here
})

describe("testing the add endpoint", function () {
    console.log("testing the API now!")
    it("add endpoints result should evaluate to 10", function (done) {
        fetch(`${BASE_URL}add/5/5`)
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.result).to.be(10)
            })
            .then(done) // <- here
            .catch(done) // <- here
    })
})
after("shutting down the server..", function (done) {
    httpServer.close(done) // <- here
})
```

As you can see here, I have NOT attached the `then` statement to the `it` function.

```
fetch(`${BASE_URL}add/5/5`).then(response => expect(response.result).to.be(10)).then(done).catch(done)
```

If this does not solve your issue, then there is likely an issue with the route for `/add/5/5`.

Comment: You cannot call .then on the it function?

Comment: @JonasGrønbek `then` is part of the `fetch` promise chain, it's not attached to `it`.

Comment: hotzinger it() does not return a promise, and I have tried your solution, and it runs but does not solve the warning apparently.

Comment: I think you're having trouble reading the code I provided. So I'll make it a one liner...

Comment: I have tried it, and it does not solve it mate. I can push to github if you're up for solving this mystery. I am sorry, but it was not the case.

Comment: You should probably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you should probably see my real codebase, I have no clue how to simplify more